# Почему div внутри другого div'a не хочет центрироваться

Tags: html, css, выравнивание

```css
.yey {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.block {
  border: 1px solid green;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
}

.p {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 200px;
}

.title {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="yey">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="title">TITLE</div>
    <div class="p">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, unde!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: уберите ширину 200px у тега <p>

Comment: Что куда не центрируется? Ничего не понятно.

Comment: @Air не следует менять код автора, даже если Вы стремитесь сделать его более понятным (как в данном случае). Это будет более уместно в Вашем ответе, а вот авторы могут Вас не понять

Answer (score 4):

Это удобно и легко сделать с помощъю [Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex):

```
.block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.title, .p {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.p {
  max-width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Рабочий пример на основе Вашего кода:

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.title, .p {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.p {
  max-width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <div class="title">TITLE</div>
    <div class="p">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, unde!
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
.yey {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.block {
  border: 1px solid green;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
}

.p {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.title {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="yey">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="title">TITLE</div>
    <div class="p">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, unde!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

у дива, по дефолту 100% ширина, куда ему центрироваться ?)

```
    .title {
text-align: center;
}
```